# Pandas: Groupby Fill disappear the column

Tags: pandas

I have dataframe. I am doing a groupby and doing a ffill. Post this I can't see the column over which I grouped. Why? What can I do to mitigate this? My code below:

```
df.groupby(["col1"], as_index=False).fillna(method="ffill")
```

Comment: Could you post an example dataframe, also your pandas version. your code works fine for me in pandas 0.25.1 for a sample df

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method="ffill"))
```

#### Why applying apply method?

Group by is - split-apply-combine.

Group by groups can be divided into 4 parts.

**Aggregation**

Aggregation functions can be directly applied on groupby because we are applying these functions on groups.

```
df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).mean()
```

**Transformation**

Transformation allows us to perform some computation on the groups as a whole and then return the combined DataFrame. This is done using the transform() function.

```
df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

**Filteration**

Filtration allows us to discard certain values based on computation and return only a subset of the group. We can do this using the filter() function in Pandas.

```
df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).filter(any_filter_function)
```

**Apply**

Pandas’ apply() function applies a function along an axis of the DataFrame. When using it with the GroupBy function, we can apply any function to the grouped result.

```
df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.fillna(method="ffill"))
```